# Cannot get Wizard Example to work in GateIn 3.1 GA

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets, gatein

I cannot get the [Richfaces wizard example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/include.jsf?c=include&tab=usage) to work in GateIn 3.1.

I am using JSF 1.2, Facelets 1.1.15, GateIn 3.1 GA, Richfaces 3.3.3, IE8.

I am reposting here as I have had good luck on stackoverflow in the past (originally posted on JBoss user forum but did not receive any responses).

I have created the files exactly as in the example but when I click Next button on the first page, the next page does not get included (display does not change).

I should add that I have the same problem trying to get Max Katz model wizard example described here:
http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/06/richfaces-wizard-inside-modal-panel/

I am having same issue in IE8 and Chrome.

Note: I've also tried adding `<redirect/>` to the navigation-rules and when I click Next button then entire portlet goes to a blank page.

Is there any help in debugging this? I turned up log4j to DEBUG but don't see any hints as to what is wrong.

The other difference is that we use Spring.

Here is the `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <application>
        <view-handler>org.jboss.portletbridge.application.PortletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <state-manager>org.jboss.portletbridge.application.PortletStateManager</state-manager>
    </application>

    <!-- SPRING INTEGRATION TO JSF -->
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>profile</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.Profile</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/wstep1.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/wstep2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule> 

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/wstep2.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/wstep1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/finalStep.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule> 

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/finalStep.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/richfaces/include/examples/wstep2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Here is bean in `spring-beans.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="profile" class="com.Profile" scope="request" >
</bean>
```

Here is `start.xhtml` (exactly from demo):

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <style type="text/css">
        .col1 { vertical-align:top; }
        .col2 { vertical-align:top; width:450px; }
        .wizard { width:400px; }
        .wform td { vertical-align:top; }
        .wfcol1 { text-align: right; white-space:nowrap;}
        .wfcol2 { }
        .wfcol3 { }
        .s1row td { height:30px; }
        .rich-message { color:red;  }
        .navPanel {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:23px;
            margin:0;
            padding:2px;
        }
    </style>
    <br/>
    <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="2" columnClasses="col1,col2">
        <a4j:keepAlive beanName="profile" />
        <rich:panel styleClass="wizard">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Using a4j:include for Wizard-like behaviour" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form>
                <a4j:include viewId="/richfaces/include/examples/wstep1.xhtml" />
            </h:form>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <br/>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is `wstep1.xhtml` (this page gets loaded in portlet initially):

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <div style="position:relative;height:140px">
        <h:panelGrid rowClasses="s1row" columns="3" columnClasses="wfcol1,wfcol2,wfcol3">
            <h:outputText value="First Name:" />
            <h:inputText id="fn" value="#{profile.firstName}" label="First Name" required="true" />
            <rich:message  for="fn" />

            <h:outputText value="Last Name:" />
            <h:inputText  id="ln" value="#{profile.lastName}"  label="Last Name"  required="true" />
            <rich:message  for="ln" />

            <h:outputText value="Company:" />
            <h:inputText id="comp" value="#{profile.company}"  label="Company"  required="true" />
            <rich:message for="comp"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <div class="navPanel" style="width:100%;">
            <a4j:commandButton style="float:right" action="next" value="Next &gt;&gt;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is `portlet.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portlet-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>Rule Portlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Rule Editor</display-name>
        <portlet-class>javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
            <value>/start.xhtml</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>javax.portlet.faces.preserveActionParams</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Rule Editor</title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Here is `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Filter Portal</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.portletbridge.WRAP_SCRIPTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.portlet.faces.renderPolicy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALWAYS_DELEGATE</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.RESOURCE_URI_PREFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>rfRes</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Spring Configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.IS_SAVE_BINDINGS_STATE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
        <param-value>com.CustomResourceResolver</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be problem with three last params in your web.xml. They'r known to cause problems with AJAX (I also had these problems). There is only little documentation about these params. Although I found this comments about them:

```
<!-- Undocumented, so using "default"...(should be used in conjunction with following 2 parameters)
<context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.IS_SAVE_BINDINGS_STATE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
-->
<!-- http://javaspecialist.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/performance-tuning-of-seam-jsf-richfaces-for-webapps/
BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE:
         Idea behind using buildBeforeRestore is to restore the view even if the associated session
         has expired and thereby avoiding the ViewExpiredException.
         Setting it to true, Facelets can build view before request processing
         instead of state saving. But this will cause some other issues.
 RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE:
         In JSF 1.2 with Facelets, you can reduce the memory overhead by not saving
         the ValueExpressions. But for this you also need to set
         the BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE to true, which can cause unpredictable behaviour
         for the components.

This paramS from facelets is notorious for breaking some of the Ajax components.
Seen with Richfaces Ajax4jsf. There isn’t any documented work around for this.
Hence explicitly turn both BUILD_BE… and RECREATE… to false.
-->
```

And source of this knowledge:
http://code.google.com/p/java-education/source/browse/trunk/JPA-Spring-JSF/CZU-PEF-DataModelling/web-gui/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml?spec=svn200&r=200

So I suggest commenting out this from your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
        <param-value>com.CustomResourceResolver</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Hope it will be of any help.